# MSSQL update only if current value is greater than previous

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have database with fields
id,studentname, highestmarks

Now the student gets new marks, I want to update the database with new marks, but only if new marks are greater than the value stored in field "highestmarks" else I don't want to update.

In MySQL this can be achieved using GREATER function, but I don't know about MS-SQL

Comment: Where do you get new marks from?IS it a form?

Comment: no, why? I am just giving an example, I need the raw query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server also has the same condition, just use '>' for "greater than" or '<' for "less than". Add '=' to add equality into the mix: '<=' or '>='

```
update students
    set highestmark = 5 -- insert new value here
where id = 42-- insert id
and highestmark < 5 -- insert new value here
```

Comment: In a concurrent environment, is this subject to race conditions? I would imagine so, but not sure.